# How do you know when you are ready for game programming?

Tags: c#, c++, java

I've been programming for a while now and I want to make games or game engines. But I don't really know how much of programming one does need to learn to have the proper knowledge to make games. My question is, how hard it it really ? And what is the proper knowledge of programming when you're getting started ?

I've programmed mostly in C#, Java and C++.

Comment: While the answers to this are rather opinion-based, I think the mods are being a bit trigger happy here. For what it's worth, I started programming by making games because that's what I wanted to do and it is fun. Don't worry about if you are a great programmer yet. That comes in time and with due diligence. Find some game-dev tutorials and get your feet wet. Worry about improving your skills as you go. It took me over a decade before I could really think of myself as a good programmer but I had already made loads of cools stuff by then. As a programmer, you never stop learning.

Comment: The issue is that game programming and game design are very wide topics. There is very low level (and hard to handle) stuff you might encounter as a programmer and high level stuff (challenging) as well. We don't know what you really want to do next in life (or what you have done so far) so we can't say if you are ready or aren't ready. Skill build up when you use them and learn from others who possess them. Game development is too wide a subject to make any observations about ones readiness without any specificities about what that individual wishes to do and what he is *already* capable of.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically start leaning to program by making games. To learn game-specific programming knowledge you must make games. There is no grand preparation ceremony you must complete before you can make games.

Like any other skill, it's all just practice and repetition. Make games. Make lots of little games.

Don't start with a big project or grand idea. Start with Pong, move on to Tetris, etc.

Comment: Someone once said. "It's is better to learn how to properly use a paint brush so you can paint whatever you want instead of learning how to copy Mona Lisa one hundred times. " Does this also apply for programming ?

Comment: @felix9801: random fortune cookie-esque words of wisdom can be applied to any situation. Either way, properly learning how to "use a paint brush" requires you to actually use one. You could practice poorly ("copy Mona Lisa") or you could practice well; either way, you have to practice. Copying a game _design_ like Pong or Tetris really has nothing to do with copying in programming so there's no real connection between a programmer reimplementing games and recreating a painting, unless of course you are actually copy-and-pasting code.